# Connecting Cassandra DB using Jmeter

Tags: cassandra, jmeter, performance-testing, cassandra-2.0, jmeter-plugins

I am completely new to Cassandra DB .I used the Jmeter plugin after following the steps provided [here](https://github.com/Netflix/CassJMeter/wiki/getting_started) but getting error .

```
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to find Creating Connection class 'com.netflix.jmeter.connections.a6x.AstyanaxConnection'
        com.netflix.jmeter.sampler.Connection.getInstance(Connection.java:148)
        com.netflix.jmeter.sampler.GetSampler.execute(GetSampler.java:9)
        com.netflix.jmeter.sampler.AbstractSampler.sample(AbstractSampler.java:205)
        org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:465)
        org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
        org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried cassandra-java-driver-2.0.2.tar as well , but not able to connect .
Can anyone guide me the steps/code to connect to Cassandra DB using Jmeter.

Updating the screen shots of Jmeter

[image: Schema Properties]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems an **installation** issue.

try out the steps [here](https://github.com/Netflix/CassJMeter/wiki/Installation-Instruction)

**Building JMeter Plugin** (.jar file)

```
git clone http://github.com/Netflix/CassJMeter.git ~/CassJMeter

cd ~/CassJMeter

mvn dependency:copy-dependencies install -DexcludeGroupIds=org.apache.jmeter
```

Note: the `'-DexcludeGroupIds=org.apache.jmeter'` parameter tells maven not to copy the jmeter jars into the target dependencies directory. This is necessary if you run a different version of jmeter than what this plugin compiles against as when you copy over the CassJMeter jars (see below) you will end up with different versions of the ApacheJMeter jar in jmeter's lib directory, which really confuses the app when it tries to run.

**Copy the artifacts into the JMeter lib and lib/ext Directory’s.** (so JMeter can access them)

```
cd ~/jmeter

cp -Rf ~/CassJMeter/target/CassJMeter-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar lib/ext/

cp -Rf ~/CassJMeter/target/dependency/* lib/
```

You are all set, You can start the JMeter UI by running `cd ~/jmeter; bin/jmeter`

Comment: Naveen, I did the same steps for installation . I could see all the Cassandra sampler in the UI . I added the Cassandra properties ,Schema properties & Cassandra get sampler as well . the error occurs while running it .

Comment: can you please add the screenshots of the Cassandra related configuration done in JMeter?

Comment: I have updated the screenshots of my test scenario as you requested .

Comment: Naveen, plugins for Cassandra is installed correctly in my jmeter as i could see all the related samplers , it seems the problem is related to 'com.netflix.jmeter.connections.a6x.AstyanaxConnection' class . It may be compatibility issues (not sure ) . I tried both with Jmeter3.0 and Jmeter2.73 . have you tried this jmeter plugin or any other methods. if so, will it be possible to share me the steps ?

Comment: 1. try the same values that are specified in `cassandra.yaml`. clusterName,keySpace, column_family etc.  2. Keep CasandraProperties ahead of SchemaProperties in the hierarchy of the test plan. 3.try with JMeter 2.9 version

Comment: I tried now and I am able to send the requests (though the server is not installed) after fixing above problems without any issues (getting connection timeout as server is not there). so follow the same. may be the compatibility issue, so use JMeter 2.9 as specified in Installation_Instructions. make sure you provide all valid properties.